# How To Setup Apache behind nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to run Apache behind nginx. because, i want to use **(.htaccess)** Rewrite rules.
Currently Apache is running on port 80 with nginx running on port 8080. nginx to serve only static files (jpg,png,css,js...) rest of the things to handle by Apache.

Which apache mod? **mod_rpaf** or **mod_proxy**

Apache & nginx configuration?

Comment: check my answer here "http://stackoverflow.com/a/18351148/2149092"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some things backwards. If Nginx is in "front", it should be on port 80, not Apache. Also, the proxying is done by Nginx. Apache needs no proxy module installed in this configuration.

Nginx also has it's own rewrite module, and [recommends against using .htaccess files](http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess).

There are lots of tutorials already out there when searching for [using nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache]. I recommend checking one for details.

Comment: i have to install lot of Scripts.every time i need to configure nginx.so, i want working .htaccess